# Making 9 patch image from ribbon icon doesnt strecth correctly

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

I got this image and i need to make 9 patch of it (i am using it for textview background). 
[image]

I need the text to appear text to left of star like this:
[image]

I tried this but with no success:

[image]

Is this even possible or do i have to use something else than 9 patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use-case is exactly what 9-patch was invented for, so it should work!

Here are some common errors that might occur while using nine-patches:

- Did you make your image with the [draw9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)-tool ? Making it in photoshop or another photo-editing app, it is possible that the outer pixels are not completely white or black.
- Is your filename correct ? (ending in .9.png)
- If you put your nine-patch image in a resource-folder with a **larger density** then the device's density you are testing on, the image is probably scaled down and one of your black-pixels (on the left or the top) are removed.

You can solve this by either

1. Providing nine-patches for all densities (ldpi, **mdpi**, hdpi, **xhdpi**) (bold ones are the most common ones) ***<-- Preferred!***
2. Make your nine-patch for xhpdi and draw a minimum of 2 black pixels. Because when scaling down from xhdpi to mdpi, your image is scaled down with a factor of 2, so if you only draw 1 black pixel in xhdpi, it might be removed when scaling down.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: My problem is that i dont know how to create stretch and content marks in 9 patch to achieve the desired.